# Inject service into controller when in different files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have this controller and service in a `storage.js` file:

```
angular.module('app', []).

    controller('storageController', ['$scope', 'storage', function ($scope, storage) {
                                    $scope.loadProducts = function() {
                                        storage.loadProducts();
                                    };
                                    $scope.saveProducts = function(json) {
                                        storage.saveProducts(json);
                                    };
                                }])
    .service('storage', [function() {
                        this.loadProducts = function loadProducts() {
                            plugincoredata.loadProducts(function(success) {
                                    alert('SUCCESS: ' + success);
                                },
                                function(error) {
                                    alert('ERROR: ' + error);
                                }
                            );

                        };
                        this.saveProducts = function saveProducts(json) {
                            bancacoredata.saveProducts(function(success) {
                                    alert('SUCCESS: ' + success);
                                },
                                function(error) {
                                    alert('ERROR: ' + error);
                                },
                                json
                            );
                        };
                       }]);
```

Then I have this utils service I am trying to create in a `utils.js` file:

```
    angular.module('app', [])
    .service('utils', [function() {
                       var amICordova = null;
                       this.isCordova = function isCordova() {
                            if (amICordova == null) {
                                amICordova = lastIndexOf('http://', 0) !== 0 && lastIndexOf('https://', 0) !== 0;
                            }
                            return amICordova;
                       };
    }]);
```

I want to inject this service into the controller so that I can identify if the webapp is running as a cordova app or normal web browser before I save the data using native SQLite or IndexedDB. I tried with `controller('storageController', ['$scope', 'storage', 'utils', function ($scope, storage, 'utils')` but I got an error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=utilsProvider%20%3C-%20utils

How can I inject this service into the controller?

Comment: You dnt create the same module twice `angular.module('app', [])`. You probably meant ` angular.module('app').service('utils'`

Comment: While I understand the reasoning for off-topic (the part saying "simple typographical error"), that is a wrong assumption. I thought that it was possible to add a service in a different file while specifying the same module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `utils.js` file, you should set other module name.(Like commons)

```
angular.module('commons', [])
.service('utils', [function() {
   ...
}]);
```

In your `storage.js` file : Load the commons module.

```
angular.module('app', ['commons'])
.controller('storageController', ['$scope', 'storage', 'utils', function ($scope, storage, utils){
...
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Too obvious I am a complete javascript and AngularJS newbie :-P

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want any common module, you can define your service like this :

`var app = angular.module('app',[]);//creating module`

`app.service('utils', [function() {
      /*insert your code here*/
}]);`

Using this format will ensure you dont *re-create* the module by mistake.
And then in you controller you can inject the service like :

`app.controller('storageController', ['$scope', 'storage', 'utils', function ($scope, storage, utils) { 
    /*controller code here*/
}]);`

Comment: Thanks, I was aware that this works but I prefer having the utils functions in a separate file as I am sure more and more common utils will keep getting added to this service in order to handle common tasks across several controllers and services.

Comment: When you are sure that you will keep adding to utils then the solution by Steven is what you should go for. And keep your watch on `angular.module('app', [])` which recreates the module. Assigning it to a `var` helps in such cases.